# How to create dropdown with multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]!
Hi I am using Excel 2003. I need to add data validation to a column, it should display the two columns in the cell, when user selects, the 1st column value should be displayed in cell.

Ex:

> Col1 Col2
>   IND India
>   CHI China

Column - display to select

> Column
>   IND-India
>   CHI-China

after selecting `CHI` the `China` or `CHI` will be displayed in the cell.

Is there any possibility to do the process in Excel.

Thanks in advance for any help...
[image]

Answer (score 3):

## (1)

If you need a dropdown item to display a different title after being selected, you can have another cell serve as the display.  For example:

[image: Dropdown Example]

Where **B3** (the helper cell) can have a formula like `=LEFT($C$3,3)` or use INDEX/MATCH to look up keys (like in your 'For Validation' table).

And where **C3** (the data validation list) has a custom format like `;;;"(Change)"` or "(Select)" or even a symbol like "↓", and will never display the actual selected list item.

You can also **do this with VBA** by creating an activex combo box control.

## (2)

If you need one dropdown list to depend on the selection made in another, you can use dynamic dependent data validation:
http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-19-dynamic-dependent-data-validation

Answer (score 1):

Go to Devloper tab - insert - active control- insert comobobox
draw comobox in your excel sheet
right click on combobox, open property
in listfill range, type range of your column
set coloumn count = 2
change the widht of colomn

Answer (score -1):

You can use the dropdown menu for the first column and the VLOOKUP function for the second column.

VLOOKUP would look at the first column and based on what's there would fill the second with the data from somewhere else.

I've also found a YouTube tutorial on how to use the function. Here you go:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WAEzokHSJM