# Excel dropdown with name/value pairs

Tags: excel

I have workbook with 2 worksheets.

"Sheet2" has two columns:

```
|    A    |      B        |
+---------+---------------+
|  code1  | description 1 |
|  code2  | Descr 2       |
```

Sheet1 has several columns, one of them (column D) is **code**. In this column i need a "drop box", what

- will show column Sheet2!B (the descriptions), and when the user selects one description
- will enter the `code` from the col:A.

It is possible to do `without additional helper column` in Sheet1? (Excel 2010)

So, need something what is dead simple in html:

```
<select>
  <option value="code1">Description 1</option>
  <option value="code2">Descr 2</option>
</select>
```

when when the user selects "Descr 2", the form get "code2".

This question probably is an duplicate - but i'm not sure - to:
[How to create dropdown with multiple columns in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580581/how-to-create-dropdown-with-multiple-columns-in-excel), but the only answer to it pointing me to an [external site](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/05/a-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/) where the solution is for another problem.

Added a screenshot for more precise explanation:
[image]

Answer (score 20):

**Simple!**
Here is what we are going to get!

[image]

**3 Steps Only:**

1. Define a range to use as the lookup value
2. Create the dropdown list
3. Paste in some code

---

**Step 1:** Setup `Sheet2` like this and define a *Named Range* as `_descrLookup`:

[image: define a named range for the VLookup]

```
( Highlight -> Right-Click -> "Define Name..." )
```

> This is an optional step, but it just makes it easy to follow for Step 3.

---

**Step 2:** In `Sheet1`, create the dropdown using *Data Validation* and use the VALUES YOU WANT TO BE SHOWN IN THE DROPDOWN as the source. In this example it's `Sheet2 A2:A4` (see above image):

[image: Set data validation to the source from Sheet 2]

```
( Data -> Data Validation )
```

---

**Step 3:** Add some VBA code to `Sheet1`:

```
( Right-Click the tab Sheet1 -> View Code )
```

Paste this into the code window for `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    selectedVal = Target.Value

    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedVal, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("_descrLookup"), 2, False)

        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Unfortunately I can't try the solutuion because in the Excel 2016 (15.3) for Mac OS X missing the VisualBasic macro-editing. :( +1 anyway, because your screenshot shows what i mean. :)

Comment: Oh no! Do you have the Developer's tab? If not, you can click the little gear icon at the top and go to Ribbon Preferences and enable it there. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like Data Validation (allow List) combined with VLOOKUP will do what you want.

On sheet 2 set up your description/code list. Make it a named range (helps avoid circular reference problems).

On Sheet 1, in the description column, use Data Validation to make dropdown lists that reference the description column of the list.  In the code column use the VLOOKUP function, keying off of the dropdown list value.

```
=IF(B4="", "", VLOOKUP(B4, FruitList, 2, FALSE))
```

**Updated** -

I'm starting to see what you mean by "without a helper column", but I'm not sure you can get exactly what you want.  A fact of Excel design: what you see is what you get, i.e. the value that displays in the cell is the effective value of that cell. You can't have a cell display one value but "contain" another value.  Such a thing is "dead simple" in HTML, but an HTML control isn't built for the same purpose as a cell in a spreadsheet.  It's two things at the same time: a value, and a user interface presentation of that value. A spreadsheet cell can contain a way to determine a value (dropdown list, formula, etc.) but whatever value it reaches is going to be the value it shows.

Excel has forms support with things like combo boxes but I believe the value is still output to another cell.

The usual approach to this is to use data validation to create a dropdown list and have a separate column using VLOOKUP for the code.  If you really can't have another column to contain the code then I'm not sure what to tell you.  It would depend on how the data is to be consumed; are you trying to get a printout, or is the sheet being processed by another program?

**Update 2**

If you're really bent on not using a separate code column you *may* be able to use a combo box technique as partially described here:

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal10.html

It would be complicated.  What you would have to do is (a) get the combo box to show up when the user selects one of the cells in column D, and (b) dynamically adjust the box's display items.  It would involve VBA code and I'm not 100% sure it's possible. It certainly doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: One option would be to have an data entry sheet and a data value sheet, so you use your value list in the entry screen to create your user frendly drop down but then on the value sheet you use a VLookup to turn the user friendly value into your data value
though thats a pain so most people do it on the same sheet but use a hiddent column for the value field

Comment: Additional note: you'd have to swap column A & B round for a VLookup to work

Answer (score 1):

I was able to turn on the Developer tab in Excel 2016 (15.33) for Mac OS X using the following steps:

1. In the menu select **Excel->Preferences**
2. In the **Authoring** section, click **View**
3. At the bottom of the dialog, check the **Developer tab** checkbox

[image: View dialog from Excel 2016 (15.33) for Mac OS X]

4. The Developer tab is now visible in Excel

[image: Excel main screen with Developer tab]

Comment: Yes, the Developer tab is here, but do you tried enter any VB macro? It still isn't possible. The "work is in progress", as it is [described here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac/visual-basic-support-in-mac-2016/4afbba04-4435-4970-8b02-40da006a590e) and [also here](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304933-excel-for-mac/suggestions/9098431-bring-back-a-fully-functional-vbe-visual-basic-ed)

Comment: The VB Macro worked for me on my Mac running Excel version 15.33.

Comment: That's cool. I have only 15.13.4 and I can't enter any VB macro. The editor opens, but doesn't allows enter any macro. Need do the upgrade. Thank you.